# How to find which part/group of regular expression fails

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find which part of expression fails.Let say I have a expression `^-?(\\d*)(,\\d{1,3})*(?:[,]|([.]\\d{0,2}))?$`  And I want to know if it fails while matching comma (,) or decimal part . How I can find unmatched group in given regular expression

Comment: test your regex on this http://regex101.com site.

Answer (score 1):

Break it in to smaller chunks and test that each part matches what you expect it to.

Also as @Avinash Raj has mentioned, online regex checkers like regex101 are indespensible.

These tools highlight what has and hasn't been matched in a given set of data. This will show you where the regex is failing.